# Get access to shared directory

Tags: java, linux, file, shared

The question us also related to linux but solution is needed for Java. So I have a data directory

```
/somedir/data
```

on linux server

```
servername
```

I can ssh to the server and do anything I want only from deployment machine (due public/private keys in place). But there's a Java process that should read files from that directory. How can I force it read that files? I was trying to use `File("//servername/somedir/data")` with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: any chance mounting the source directory on your machine with sshfs would help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must share the file using one of the network file services.
For example:

- NFS (check with `showmount -e`);
- Samba (check with `smbclient -L`);
- AFS;
- HTTP/FTP (check first if there a HTTP/FTP-server on the host).

You can also access this file using SSH (you say that you have SSH connection to the host, that means that SSH is accessible anyway).

If you want to connect to the SSH server from Java program, 
you can use (for example) [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) for that.
Example of JSch usage is [here](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/ScpFrom.java.html).

Comment: How can I check if target directory is shared with any of services you mentioned? Sorry if question is stupid.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it's not shared. As I have any attempt to share using extra services comes with a headache due enterprise security policies the best thing I guess is to use JSch.

Comment: Yes, JSch or other SSH-client